# Dynamic button with Lottie

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, core-animation, lottie

I want to create button with three different states namely Initial, Loading, Completed.

**UI for button state:**

[image]

Initial -> TextLabel

[image]

Loading -> Loading indicator/multiple images

[image]

Completed -> TextLabel

It will be in **Initial** state normally when user clicks it then It will change its state to **Loading** with transforming itself to show loading indicator inside it. Once completed it will animate and transform to show the label.

How can I achieve it with Lottie? 
I need to set initial and completed state texts dynamically but as per the docs I couldn't find out a way to change text into Lottie.

With Lottie I can use progress animation to handle different states of button but how can I change texts programatically without new json file.

Lottie doesn't support text layer in iOS. Any workaround for that except using shape layer?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the text for the Button in the JSON, via directly modifying the JSON itself programmatically. As Lottie animation and views are governed by JSON, it's not possible.

Comment: Lottie in iOS doesn't support Text layers. Do you have any workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

There's no proper API support in Lottie for this, but this thread has a discussion on possible ways you can change the text via the json file:

https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web/issues/238